# How to manage scheduling SpringBoot Applications tasks?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, job-scheduling

Currently, in our company, colleagues use @Scheduled to schedule tasks. Sometimes, the tasks would stop occasionally. So I am wondering if there could be better practices for scheduling?

Comment: Scheduled tasks can sometimes fail, as can your primary application.  Is your question asking about how to cope with possible failures?  Something else?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Usually the task could run for several days, and then since somewhat time stop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `Quartz` with spring boot. it has many more features more than the default.
https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.18.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-quartz.html

Comment: xxljob is a better choice     https://github.com/xuxueli/xxl-job/